# Is there a theory about a collision between a shrinking universe and a new expanding universe?

Tags: big-bang-theory

I recently read a post on a discussion board about the creation of our current universe that stated, and I quote:

> [T]he shrinkage activity of the old universe and the new Big Bang expansion movement still made a tremendous collision, resulting in the diffusion and spiral of fine particles.The diffusion of fine particles was integrated into a swirl to reduce the collision and the thermal activity became mature, but the expansion of the fine particle spiral group by the Big Bang is still progressing, expanding while colliding with the shrinking old matters of the old universe There. New matters cooperate solidly with a spiral net to the whole universe as a gear that rotates at the same speed.

I am just an amateur interested in astronomy, but I have never heard of a theory regarding such an event before. Is this a known theory that has been researched?

Comment: No, it's not. The quoted text is basically physically meaningless gibberish.

Comment: Wow, there I was thinking that the old universe was made of unused dark Higgs matter enmeshed in spiral antigraviton webs that catch Luminous Galaxies as they spew out of the Great White Hole at the other end of our hyperspace E-R worm bridge. But it turns out (according to the last paragraph) that we're just a cog in a machine. * Sigh. *